# $\beth_\xi=\sum_{\eta<\xi}2^{\beth_{\eta}}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> If $\xi>0$ is an ordinal, then
> $$\beth_\xi=\sum_{\eta<\xi}2^{\beth_{\eta}}.$$

This is my attempt:

By definition of the beth function,
$$\beth_\xi=\sum_{\eta<\xi}\beth_\eta.$$

Therefore, since $2^{\beth_\alpha}=2^{\beth_{\alpha+1}}$,
$$\beth_\xi=\sum_{\eta<\xi}\beth_\eta=\sum_{\eta<\xi}2^{\beth_{\eta-1}}=\sum_{\eta<\xi}2^{\beth_\eta}.$$

I think I can't do the first step, because $\xi$ must be a limit ordinal. Any hint, please? :(

Comment: For transfinite induction you need to prove (i) $\xi=0$ works (vacuous in this case), (ii) if $\alpha$ works so does $\alpha^+$, and (iii) if $\xi\ne0$ is a limit ordinal with each $m<\xi$ working, so does $\xi$. (General point: if in (iii) $\xi\ne0$ can be dropped, you can skip (i).) It looks like in (ii) you've incorrectly described its inductive hypothesis as a consequence of $\beth$'s definition, which is closer to what (iii) needs.

Comment: @J.G. I'm confused... If $\xi=0$, then 
$$\beth_0=\aleph_0=\sum_{\eta<0}\beth_\eta=0,$$

but this is a contradiction. So $\xi=0$ doesn't hold. :(

Comment: Ah, but it does, because the claim to prove states _if $\xi\ne0$ then..._, which as I said is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) if $\xi=0$. Anyway, focus on (ii) & (iii).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$
\sum_{\eta<\xi+1} \beth_\eta = \sum_{\eta\leq\xi} \beth_\eta = \beth_\xi
$$